# OpenSSL ECDH setting peer's public key in C

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, openssl

I'm trying to integrate ECDH using OpenSSL in my C-SDK (which we will refer to as client) which is running on **Ubuntu** and needed some help regarding how to set the peer's (server) public key on the client side and eventually generating the shared secret.

#### Some details:

1. I am successfully generating a public key and can also generate a shared secret on the server side which has an embedded microcontroller using the `mbedTLS` library.
2. The public key I receive from the server is in the form of a `uint8_t` array of size `32 bytes`.
3. I now want to use OpenSSL's ECDH to generate the public key for server and the shared secret on the client side.

I found a sample code on the [OpenSSL wiki website](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman) which is as below:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>


unsigned char *ecdh(size_t *secret_len)
{
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx, *kctx;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    unsigned char *secret;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL, *peerkey, *params = NULL;
    /* NB: assumes pkey, peerkey have been already set up */

    /* Create the context for parameter generation */
    if(NULL == (pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_EC, NULL))) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the parameter generation */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init(pctx)) handleErrors();

    /* We're going to use the ANSI X9.62 Prime 256v1 curve */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid(pctx, NID_X9_62_prime256v1)) handleErrors();

    /* Create the parameter object params */
    if (!EVP_PKEY_paramgen(pctx, &params)) handleErrors();

    /* Create the context for the key generation */
    if(NULL == (kctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL))) handleErrors();

    /* Generate the key */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(kctx)) handleErrors();
    if (1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen(kctx, &pkey)) handleErrors();

    /* Get the peer's public key, and provide the peer with our public key -
     * how this is done will be specific to your circumstances */
    peerkey = get_peerkey(pkey);

    /* Create the context for the shared secret derivation */
    if(NULL == (ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL))) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_init(ctx)) handleErrors();

    /* Provide the peer public key */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(ctx, peerkey)) handleErrors();

    /* Determine buffer length for shared secret */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive(ctx, NULL, secret_len)) handleErrors();

    /* Create the buffer */
    if(NULL == (secret = OPENSSL_malloc(*secret_len))) handleErrors();

    /* Derive the shared secret */
    if(1 != (EVP_PKEY_derive(ctx, secret, secret_len))) handleErrors();

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(peerkey);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(kctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(params);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);

    /* Never use a derived secret directly. Typically it is passed
     * through some hash function to produce a key */
    return secret;
}
```

The example has a `peerkey = get_peerkey(pkey);` line where it sets the peerkey and basically leaves it on the user to implement this function. I would imagine it would be straightforward if I was using OpenSSL on the server side as well.

#### My question:

Referring to the above code,and keeping in mind that I'm receiving the server's public key as a `uint8_t` array, how do I set the `EVP_PKEY *peerkey` context so that it contains the server's public key?

If there's another straight-forward crypto library in C that I can use on Ubuntu then please do suggest!

Really appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they are about cryptography. Programming questions belong on stackoverflow; I can migrate this there for you.

Comment: Hi @EllaRose 
Thank you for clarifying and migrating it to stackoverflow :)

Thank you!

Comment: (1) A prime256v1=secp256r1=P-256 public key is never 32 bytes; it is either 33 bytes compressed or 65 bytes uncompressed. Are you sure you aren't publishing your private key and destroying all security? (2) There are many crypto libraries, but if you like mbed [it is packaged on Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mbedtls)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The server side is using the x25519 curve. The example above was only taken from the openSSL wiki and their default example was using the `prime256v1` curve.
Thanks for sharing the link though. I have tested both client and server key exchange on my embedded microcontroller successfully using mbedtls and that works fine. I was thinking of using some other crypto library on the c-sdk side running on ubuntu so I can verify the end to end properly and make sure it works with the commonly used crypto libs out there :)